# $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ Voronoi diagrams and tropical geometry: Connection?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, tropical-geometry

I just realized that there is a visual similarity between Voronoi diagrams in
the $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ metrics (two images below)

---

[image: L1LinfVorDiag]

 
<sub>Left: O'Rourke, "Computing Relative Neighborhood graph in the $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ metrics," *Pattern Recognition*, 1982.

 
Right: "What-If Emergency Response Through Higher Order Voronoi Diagrams,"
*Ann  Info Sys Security Info*, 2010 ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-1325-8_5#page-1)).</sub>

---

and two-variable polynomial "curves" in tropical geometry (two images below):

---

[image: Cubic]

 
<sub>From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry).</sub>

 [image: NineCubics]

 
<sub>From [TropicalGeom link](http://www.crcg.de/wiki/Tropical_geometry_in_enumerative_geometry)</sub>

---

Because the $L_\infty$ metric is based on the max coordinate differences, and
tropical addition is the max of two numbers, and because there is an 
isometry between the $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ metrics, it makes sense that there
might be a connection. I wonder if this is the case; and if so, has it been explored?

Comment: I just noticed this in my own research and wanted to see if anyone else also came up with the idea! I don't believe the idea has been explored before and I will add an answer if I am able to find any concise conclusions.

Comment: There is at least a connection between *L2* voronoi diagrams and tropical geometry, in that computing the voronoi diagram of a set of point is equivalent to projecting those points to a paraboloid and finding the intersections of the corresponding tangent planes.  See the second-to-last diagram on [this page](http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~pless/506/l17.html) and also [this diagram](http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/projects/internal-projects/vd-via-dc-of-envelopes/figs/env-plane.jpg).